# Как найти последней элемент по ключу в односвязном списке

Tags: c#, односвязный-список

Реализован такой односвязный список, с методами поиска, добавления.

```
public class Node
{
    public Node Next;
    public int Value;

    public Node(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class SinglyLinkedList
{
    public Node Head;
    private int count = 0;

    // Колличество элементов в всписке 
    public int GetCount()
    {
        return count;

    }
    // Вывод элементов списка
    public string Print()
    {
        string result = "";
        Node current = Head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            result += current.Value + " ";
            current = current.Next;
        }

        return result;
    }
    // Нахождение первого элемента списка по ключу
    public Node Find(int key)
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Node current = Head;
        while (current.Value != key)
        {
            current = current.Next;
            if (current == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return current;
    }
    // Нахождение последнего элемента списка 
    private Node FindTail()
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Node current = Head;
        while (current.Next != null)
        {
            current = current.Next;
        }

        return current;
    }
    // Добавление элемента в конец 
    public void PushBack(int item)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(item);
        if (count == 0)
        {
            Head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            Node tail = FindTail();
            tail.Next = newNode;
        }

        count++;
    }
    // Добавление элемента в начало 
    public void PushFront(int item)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(item);

        if (count != 0)
        {
            newNode.Next = Head;
        }

        Head = newNode;
        count++;
    }
    // Добавление элемента после 
    public void AddAfter(Node node, int item)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Node newNode = new Node(item);

        newNode.Next = node.Next;
        node.Next = newNode;

        count++;
    }
}
```

Нужно создать метод  который возвращает последний узел (Node), содержащий указанное значение. Если такого узла нет, то метод возвращает null:
Дошел до реализации метода таким образом, но мне кажется что это не совсем верно

```
public Node FindLast(int key)
{
    Node current = Head;
    Node prev = null;
    Node temp = null;
    if (count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current.Next.Value == key)
        {
            prev = current;
            temp = current.Next;
        }
        current = current.Next;
        if (current.Next == null)
            break;

    }
    
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавлю вторым ответом.

Вы могли бы код чутка упростить, если бы сделали приватный метод для перебора элементов и воспользовались Linq там, где нужен перебор.

Пример:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList
{
    public Node Head;
    private int count = 0;

    // Колличество элементов в всписке 
    public int GetCount()
    {
        return count;
    }
    
    private IEnumerable<Node> Enumerate()
    {
        Node current = Head;
        while(current != null) 
        {
            yield return current;
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }
    
    // Вывод элементов списка
    public string Print()
    {
        return String.Join(" ", Enumerate().Select(x=>x.Value));
    }
    // Нахождение первого элемента списка по ключу
    public Node Find(int key)
    {
        return Enumerate().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Value == key);
    }
    // Нахождение последнего элемента списка 
    private Node FindTail()
    {
        return Enumerate().LastOrDefault();
    }

    public Node FindLast(int key)
    {
        return Enumerate().LastOrDefault(x=>x.Value == key);
    }
}
```

Можно вообще реализовать `IEnumerable<Node>` и тогда вам и методы эти однострочные не понадобятся.

Ну и полезные исходнички для изучения - [тыц](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs)

Answer (score 4):

Пишу практически с телефона, так что компилируемость не гарантирую, но логика примерно такая

```
public Node FindLast(int key)
{
    Node current = Head;
    Node ret = null;

    while(current != null)
    {
        if (current.Value == key) ret = current;
        current = current.Next;
    }

    return ret;
}
```